# Want to root Using windows which is on VirtualBox.How do i make it recognise the fone when phone is off?

Tags: rooting, usb, rom-flashing

I want to root my phone (Micromax A52) and i got the procedure.

But I use Ubuntu for everyday use and now for rooting i need Windows.

I installed it in virtualbox. Now in vbox,the usb device is recognised only if the host recognizes it.

But with the phone off for the flash process, how can i make the guest windows recognise the phone as ubuntu does not recognise

Comment: You might get better results with VMware.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ADB drivers on Ubuntu, try performing the tasks of installing busybox and su manually as detailed here - http://androidforums.com/a52-all-things-root/586982-how-root-any-android-device-manually.html

The author has used Nautilus on Ubuntu to perform the requisite tasks. YMMV, though upon reading through the thread.

As a workaround, perhaps you could use the root methods detailed in the relevant XDA thread(s) on a Windows machine.